# Where to upload .blend files - non-expiring links

Tags: discussion

People can upload their blend files to various site such as pasteall, google drive, and dropbox. The problem with these file hosts is that:

- pasteall: links expire after 5 months
- dropbox/drive: upload can delete the file

All of these file suffer from the fact that the file could quite easily be gone. This would be bad because some answer include demo scenes that are helpful and add value to the answer/question. Should we use other filehosts such as [sendspace](https://www.sendspace.com/) which also host illegal content but do not expire and also have to be uploaded by someone with a premium account?

Comment: Related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-a-service-for-uploading-blendfiles?rq=1 and http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/policy-for-linking-to-blend-files?rq=1

Comment: I spoke to members of our community team several times regarding this. Once we are out of beta this will more than likely be added as a normal upload service similar to that for images with permanently available files.

Comment: @iKlsR thats great to hear. I hope we can migrate them once we are out of beta.

Answer (score 22):

We now have

[image]

an unofficial solution... built to solve exactly this problem!

- Built just for this site
- Stores files on google drive
- Files don't get deleted
- Open source

[see more](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/3127)

Answer (score 2):

I think the only real solution to this is to have our own hosting service. See [this post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-a-service-for-uploading-blendfiles?rq=1) for more info.