# Including a .blend file

Tags: discussion, faq

How do I put a .blend file in  my questions? Thats really all I have to ask, even though I have to fit a certain amount of characters.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [**Blend-Exchange**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or [PasteAll](http://pasteall.org), both are externally offered services, the former of which is run by me. It was designed specificly for this purpose:

#### [See here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting)

The reason to use Blend-Exchange over pasteall is that the files are kept permanently -  they expire in around 5 months on pasteall.

With the [user script](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/userscript/), you can have a upload button right in the make a post box, just like an image upload.

Comment: Blend exchange is definitively the way to go. The embed code that it automatically generates for you even has an awesome, eye-catching, decorative, pretty little picture for the link to your blend file.

Comment: Hey dude it took me a couple of years thanks to a really low mouse sensitivity but I finally accepted your answer.

Comment: I've been frustrated a few times going through old questions because the OP used pasteall and I can't see the original file to see if I can diagnose a fix.