# Unanswered and abandoned questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

I had the same question as Nolan about rendering in blender, [Why won't objects appear in motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/why-wont-objects-appear-in-motion-tracking) 
But there is no answer to the question and it is a few months old with no signs of attention. **Is there any other way to spark interest in an old question, other than bounties?** I have very little rep, and don't want to waste it all. Should I ask a similar question, or will that just get marked as a duplicate? If nobody has seen the orignal question will they bother marking the new one? Perhaps we should push to close them, or put them higher on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I'd say it's okay to post your own question with a link to the old question. This is a rare exception to the rule, based off some assumptions:

- The other question has no answers (or only low-scoring answers which don't help solve the problem)
- The other question is at least a month or two old, and/or it seems unlikely that the old question's OP is readily available.
- The other question was not posted by you

If all these are true, then IMO the best course of action is to start afresh. Keep in mind that to answer a "trouble-shooting" question like this, information about the details is of the utmost importance.

A .blend is invaluable. If you don't want to upload your project to the world, take the time to try and make a simple example of the problem in a new file (or go backwards by starting with your project file and deleting unrelated objects).
See [Including a .blend file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599) for instructions on actually uploading the file.

Chances are, a lack of info is likely what resulted in the lack of answers to the other question.

With a little luck, you'll get some answers which successfully answer your question. If you do, we can close the old question as a duplicate of your new question, redirecting future visitors.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear but, I did not make the question, I simply had the same question with no answer and I don't have enough rep to edit a question.

Comment: @SammySwanson Ah, my mistake. In that case, I'd say it's fine to post a "duplicate" question of your own, perhaps with a link to the abandoned question. (IIRC closing as a duplicate of a question with 0 answers isn't even possible)

Comment: Just a side note: When the user doesn't want to or can't upload the original file, one very interesting benefit that may rise from the user trying to recreate the problem is that he often finds the solution to the problem himself.