# Why are "simple" questions so often answered in comments?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

all is in the title... but also related to [Unanswered and abandoned questions](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/unanswered-and-abandoned-questions)
So : is it good to give "clues" in comments as this will lead (probably) to unanswered questions ?

Comment: Well, speaking for myself at least, some times am not sure of the answer I am providing (like right now my stance is not at all "official") so I comment instead, either expecting further info from the user, or to encourage others to give full answers as well. Most often though I just do it because the solution is either so obviously simple or common that either I fear I am missing something fundamental or it doesn't even warrant a full featured answer. Maybe someone else cares to take the time to elaborate a full answer bellow. I'd also like to hear more opinions from other users.

Answer (score 9):

I cant speak for why everybody does it, but this is what I've seen, and done myself.

I leave an "answer" as a comment when I don't want to write a full answer, simple as that. There can be many reasons why I don't want to write a full answer: I don't have time, or don't feel like writing a full answer; I may not be 100% sure that what I'm saying is correct; I may not be sure of what the OP is asking and on and on.

Now "simple" questions *may* get answered in the comments because (people like me) don't want to take the time to write a proper answer when we can just say in one line what the OP needs to do. Yes I know we would be forfeiting the easy rep. (That may sound crazy to you now, but after you have used SE for a few years you'll see what I mean.)

Along those same lines, people may answer in the comments because it is **so** simple, they can't think of what more to write to make it a full answer.

---

It is completely up to you whether you leave "clues" in the comments.
Do bear in mind even if you "answered" in the comments and are coming back later to write a full answer your comment does not "reserve your spot." It is perfectly ok to write an answer off of somebody else's comment. (there is a lot on the SE metas on that topic)
The super short of it:

> A comment is different then an answer, as such it is a courtesy to wait for the other user to come back and answer. When you answer it would be nice to mention the comment.

I would highly recommend that you do mention the comment if you wrote your answer based off of that comment. (but that is a different issue, count all that last part a bonus.)

Comment: Considering the main interest of all these Q/A is to provide a way to find an answer in the future, maybe my question is not so important if the future user notices the comments. But there is the "avoid to answer a question in the comments". Of course I understand nobody will keep interested or will have time to do that for years... A solution could be to have the ability to tag a comment as "short answer" (or to tag an answer as short answer) ?