# Why are people downvoting my question?

Tags: discussion

In my question here I asked about an issue I was having with my model but I refused to upload the file itself due to theft in the past:

Rigging my model and the head mesh disappears

Despite this, people have still asked for the model, proof of the past theft and continually downvote my question.

What I want to know is why people are being so harsh on me for asking a question? I thought this website was about posting questions if you needed help and I checked through other questions and I'm not the only one who isn't posting their models online, so I want to know why this question is getting so much bad attention?

Is there some sort of hidden policy or formality that I've missed that everyone else is doing because I'm seriously at a loss here.

I read through my question to see if it looks like a "troll question" but it seems fine to me, so I honestly don't know why this is happening.

The model is for an upcoming video game I'm making and I have had people harass me in the past to try and get info on the game but I seriously doubt these are the same individuals, so again, any suggestions on why this question is getting so many downvotes?

I even asked that on another post when someone asked a similar question and mine was deleted. I mean I've read through the policy and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong here.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Reading this, I still can't see what I did wrong from just asking for help?

Comment: Don't give up asking more questions. Don't give up on Stackoverflow either. I was trolled on my first week, but I have stayed regardless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A downvote doesn't exactly mean you *did something wrong*, but rather your question was unclear, displayed an obvious lack of effort, or is simply something the downvoter found disagreeable.

In this case, I'd hazard a guess at "unclear" being the primary reason for your downvotes. Without a .blend exhibiting the symptoms, troubleshooting type questions like yours tend to devolve into a wild guessing game at best, especially without even a screenshot to be certain what the problem looks like.

That said, in [cases](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34074/cause-of-alpha-or-black-artefacts-in-render#comment54185_34074) like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45670/smoothing-animation-loop#comment77261_45670)), usually someone will suggest [creating a simplified version of the problem .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1122/599). I'm not sure why this hasn't been suggested yet in your case, so let me suggest it now :)
If that seems like an agreeable alternative, then [this post may be of use when simplifying](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5300/599).

Comment: I want to add: It is very likely you discover the issue and a solution while preparing a demo file just by reproducing the problematic situation. It does not only help to protect your content. It let your supporters focus on the issue rather digging through the other content of your original file.

Answer (score 8):

(full disclosure, i didn't downvote)

CraftyMaelyss - downvotes mean different things to different people (no matter what the FAQ's or Meta says about it). Getting a downvote sometimes tells you more about the person who downvoted than it does about the reason they downvoted. How people respond to downvotes can also show their maturity.

The reason people ask for a .blend is because it's the single fastest way to see if they know a solution. When you don't want to share the .blend things become more difficult and if the solution wasn't self evident from the description or images then people can only offer educated guesses (stab in the dark at worst) and that's rarely worth anyone's time.

Not sharing your .blend is of-course entirely your right and privilege (and omitting the reason for doing so is also acceptable and you don't need to invest time in justifying your reasons). But you should then provide some substitute of the .blend with parts removed or massively simplified so it offers no incentive to be "*stolen*". If you can't do that then it doesn't show the fellow site visitors that you've tried to understand the problem conceptually (outside of the current state of the .blend), and that's contrary to the goals of the community.

Answer (score 8):

Well...

As you seem to already know downvotes (DVs) do not mean people are being harsh or mean to you. In most cases it is because *there is something wrong with the post*. For a general overview see the answers: [When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/278094) But take DVs and the answer there with a grain of salt.

Try Looking at the title and first two paragraphs of your question as someone else would with no knowledge of your scene, workflow, model, rig, or anything else. Then see if from just those two paragraphs if you could solve the problem. No, nobody could answer your question with so little information.
On top of all that you have a large bold disclaimer saying how you will not upload the blend, so there is no chance anyone can help you that way.

I would say you got the DVs because your question is unclear. There is simply no way to give an answer with the information provided.