# Why there is no button for attaching a .blend directly in the editor?

Tags: discussion

I hope I won't be penalized that this is the question related to this site, not the Blender.

My question why there is already no button in the post editor that would allow to attach a .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, something like this?

[image]

I don't find handy to repeatedly paste the link into comments for almost every new question that needs more investigation of the scene.

I believe the implementation should be really easy... or is there a reason why the button (or just a simple link) is not already here?

Comment: Related: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting/634#634

Comment: Jan, I see you realized that this type of question is off topic on the main site (its only about blender). However this is exactly what the meta is for, questions about the BSE site.