# Customized help center entries

Tags: discussion, help-center

As pointed out in [Custom off-topic close reasons: 2014 in review](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/584/599), we appear to have very little site documentation about things like what you can ask about and how best to ask about it.

As a matter of fact, the only b.se specific thing I've seen in the help center is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.

This is nice, but it feels a bit short ([compared to GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) and susceptible to different interpretations.
For example, one could argue that [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23786/599) is on-topic following the above criterion.

However the best I managed to come up with right now is this:

> Blender Stack Exchange site is for people who use Blender to create 3D graphics, animations, or games.
>
> Questions about Blender using Blender are welcome.

So please edit/say something if you have a better idea ;)

---

Also, perhaps we could add something like this to the end of the "[how to ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" page?

> **Help us help you**
> Especially if your question involves troubleshooting odd behavior, the fastest and simplest way of finding the answer is often by [providing a blendfile](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/297/599) and/or screenshots for others to examine.

I'm sure there are more such snippets which could be added, but I can't think of any atm..

Comment: While we are changing the scope defined in the help center, we can include contests so they will be permitted on the main site?

Comment: @X-27 I didn't intend for this post to be about changing the scope itself, only fixing up the (lack of) wording and definition.

Comment: @X-27 There will be no contests on the main site, not now, not ever. Not in the manner you are thinking of at least. We will work something out eventually.

Comment: Will give this a day or two before we revamp this and go about setting some concrete offtopic reasons. Was hoping people would chip in but seeing the little input, I think the handful of us who read meta can come up with something sensible. Good initiative.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest that this [help center page](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), be amended to include directions as to how to upload a ~.blend file to the Blend exchange, site (or others).

Comment: I also suggest to move http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask up on second or third place in the list, so that it is visible without clicking on "view more".  I also believe that infos about imgur (for people who post the first time and cannot upload images) and of course blend-exchange could help. The "Be specific" is rather unspecific ;-) and doesn't explain much about what information is helpful (screenshots which actually show the problems by highlighting the areas of interest)