# Editing posts that require a .blend file?

Tags: discussion

I was just reading through [this question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-a-service-for-uploading-blendfiles?rq=1) about .blend file hosting, and the general consensus seems to be that it would be helpful and necessary, to have built in .blend file hosting.

The problem with this, is that it still requires downloading a file to fully understand the question, and therefore, limits the usefulness of it, and it's answer, to anyone who's looking through for their own projects.

I'm thinking that it might be a good idea, for experienced users to edit these questions, to get rid of the need for a .blend file. Adding relevant images and text, to show what a newer user has trouble understanding.

What could also help with this, is to have a separate review queue for questions that have a .blend file attached.

Those are my thoughts, what do you guys think?

Comment: We will still need file support from stack exchange, since sometimes blends are nessary/beneficial. I think it might be a tad early to make this push. There are also *litterally* thousands of blends on this site, so I wouldn't be to hasty.

Comment: Your second paragraph is excellent. I agree with part of what you said. I do not think we are in need of another review queue. However I whole hearty agree that in [some cases](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32069/2217) a blend file does not make a good question. This is something I have been saying all along, we should not put such a weight on "the file."

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Yes, there are a lot, but when we see a post like the one David linked to, if we have extra time, shouldn't we be looking into editing it to get rid of the need for a .blend file, or if the question is too situation based, close it? I understand that it is quite unpractical to completely get rid of .blend files from every post, but we could at least try to take care of newer questions. I just think a .blend file should really just be a backup instead of a primary choice for explaining a problem. Something that heavily requires a .blend file, is much more suited to a forum.

Comment: The difference whether to include an image or a blend file in a question or answer is really not about downloading the file from an external source. Both images and blend files are external downloads. The difference is that the image download is automatically performed by the software, and the user must deliberately download the ~.blend file. In some of the questions I've seen, it would take multiple images to show the information needed to form an answer, while the same information could be gained from a single ~blend file.